# Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value - freeing a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, free, valgrind

I want to free a linked list in C. All is working fine, but Valgrind is telling me

```
Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
    at 0x401400: mtf_destroy
```

Here's the code:

```
list_elt *head;

void mtf_init() {
    list_elt *current;
    head = malloc(sizeof(list_elt));
    current = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < LIST_SIZE-1; i++) {
        current->value = (BYTE) i;
        current->next = malloc(sizeof(list_elt));
        current = current->next;
    }
    current->value = LIST_SIZE-1;
}

void mtf_destroy(list_elt *elt) {
    if (elt->next != NULL)
        mtf_destroy(elt->next);
    free(elt);
}
```

How can I solve this? Thanks!

Comment: I don't see anywhere that sets the last element's `->next` to NULL.

Comment: This indeed solved the problem, as well as the solution suggested by @alk. Thanks guys

Comment: Count the number of `malloc`s your code executes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Valgrind wants to tell you the instance of `elt->next` used as expression to `if()` has not been initialize, so the decision made by `if()` is random.

You might like to change:

```
head = malloc(sizeof(list_elt));
...
  current->next = malloc(sizeof(list_elt));
```

to be:

```
head = calloc(1, sizeof(list_elt));

..."
  current->next = calloc(1, sizeof(list_elt));
```

A portable approach would be to initialise all pointers explicitly using `NULL`:

```
head = calloc(1. sizeof(list_elt));
head->next = NULL;
...
  current->next = calloc(1, sizeof(list_elt));
  current->next->next = NULL;
```

(The background to this is, that not on all systems a `NULL`-pointer necessarily is represented by a sequence of `NUL` characters (bytes)).

Anyway I'm not sure whether you assign the right thing to `next`as you did not post te definition of `list_elt`.

---

**Update:**

Regaring the recursive calls to `mtf_destroy()`:

Although recursions look cool, and are indeed an elegant solution to many problems, using them tends to be error prone, for example in case of going really deep, as they consume system resources (memory).

So if your list would be really long, destroying it might break your code.

My advice: Try doing it without recursion, at least if you can not predict the recursion levels to be performed in advance.

Comment: That fixes the symptoms, but it looks to me like the off-by-one error is still there.